# How to sort files with last modified first in c#/xaml metro app?

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am developing an app, which will show last 9 files which has been modified in gridview. Gridview item shows file name and last modified date. The latest modified file should be first and then other in decreasing order. I know there is [DateModified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.basicproperties.datemodified.aspx) property, but that's not the property of StorageFile class. So how can I use that to sort the files ? I am using GetFilesAsync() method to get all the files (which returns IReadOnlyList) but it returns files in alphabetical order. My files is in Documents library. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the Async get file Completed event and re-order the list and bind it to the grid.
Since you have the DateModified property this will not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have an instance of `StorageFile`, you could then call the [GetBasicPropertiesAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getbasicpropertiesasync.aspx) method in a loop and after all the `BasicProperties` objects are retrieved, [sort your (observable) collection](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/5909dbcc-9a9f-4260-bc36-de4aa9bbd383/),
If your collection is bound to the listview you automatically see it being displayed correctly, once the collection is sorted.